# Android SQLite query for consecutive text?

Tags: android, sqlite

Is there any sql method for querying consecutive texts from database?

For example I want to query just "koma azad" but the query method shows me "koma dengê azad", too.

Code:

```
public Cursor getmatches(String query, String[] columns) {
    String selection = KEY_WORD + " MATCH ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{query};

    return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, this is a query on a virtual table that uses fts, correct?

Comment: yeap. it is fts table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Cursor getmatchs(String query, String[] columns) {
    String selection = KEY_WORD + " MATCH ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{query};

    return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);
}
```

Solution is adding double quotes:

```
public Cursor getmatchs(String query, String[] columns) {
    String selection = KEY_WORD + " MATCH ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"\""+query+"\""};

    return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You have to use double quotes if the match phrase has separators in it. If you were to inline the query text in the selection string, it looks like this:

```
String selection = KEY_WORD + " MATCH '\"" + query + "\"'";
```

I'm not sure if this will work with the `?` placeholder character, but you can try it and let us know.